# Solve inhomogeneous wave equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I need to solve this:

$$ 
\begin{cases}
  U_{tt}= \Delta U + |x|^2 \sin t \\
  U(x,0) = |x|^4 + |x|^2 \\
  U_t(x,0) = |x|^4 - |x|^2
\end{cases}
$$

in 3 dimensions $x = \{x_1, x_2, x_3\}$

Comment: Are you looking for solutions in $\mathbb{R}^3\times [0,\infty[$? In this case, perhaps you could use *superposition principle*, *Kirckhhoff formula* and *Duhamel principle* (see Evan's PDEs book, §§2.4.1.c & 2.4.2) to build a solution... But this way to the solution really requires a lot of work.

Comment: How to rewrite the PDE in terms of the dependent variable $U$ and the independent variables $x_1$ , $x_2$ and $x_3$ ?

Comment: How to factorize $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2−t^2$ in $\mathcal{C}$ ?

Comment: Does $|x|=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Try solutions of the form
$U(x,t) = (6-|x|^2) \sin(t) + \dfrac{F(|x|+t)+ G(|x|-t)}{|x|}$

Comment: Hmm, didn't notice how old this question was.  @night-owl: why did you edit it now?  Are you interested in a solution?